# HTML: Button that links to a .html file

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a button that links to a file `(spaceRace.html)`, but I don't know how I would get the button to link to the file.

Please tell me what I should put in the button code.

```
<button type="button" onclick="">1 Player Mode</button>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Comment: What exactly does "links to a file" mean?

Comment: By clicking on the button, the webpage will change into the other webpage (which is a .html file)

Comment: Try a link `<a href...` change the styling if you need it to look like a button

Comment: khakiout: I think that is explaining how to make a button link to a WEBPAGE. I want mine to link to a .html file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<a href = "spaceRace.html"><input type = "button" style = "color:red; height:100px;width:125px; font-size:10px;font-family:'COMIC SANS MS' " value = "1 Player Mode"/></a>
```

Comment: is there a way I can change the height and width of the button? Also, how do I change the font? How do I change the button text's color and font size?

Comment: @htmlKid Use `CSS`, in this case i used `inline CSS`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I change the font of the button to something like Comic Sans?

Comment: font-family attribute,`font-family:'COMIC SANS MS'`

Comment: @htmlKid you can get all the CSS Attributes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/)